# How to get Google Drive ChangeList without trashed items

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I'm trying to list the changes in my google drive but I don't know how to list it without the Trashed files.

I'm using:

```
Changes.List changesList = service.changes().list().setIncludeDeleted(false);
```

to not include the deletion changes. But it only works for the really deleted files. The files in Trash are still listed as Change files.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `trashed = false` query when listing the files.

```
drive.files().list().setQ("trashed = false").execute();
```

For more details Please use [THIS](https://developers.google.com/drive/search-parameters)

Comment: It works for the files. The Changes resource doesnt' have that option so I have to check each file after listing the changes. I want to optimize it on the Changes check. But I believe there's no way. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The Files resource https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files#resource contains a

```
labels.trashed  boolean Whether this file has been trashed.
```

I haven't used this, but would expect it to be set correctly so your code can identify trashed files.

**EDIT**
Here is what it looks like (last line)...

```
{
"kind": "drive#changeList",
"largestChangeId": "29601",
"items": [
   {
    "kind": "drive#change",
    "id": "29591",
    "deleted": false,
    "file": {
      "kind": "drive#file",
      "id": "0B6B-RNrxsCu2d2pIQ1JYeLWs3b00",
      "title": "ntitle-0 UPADTED",
      "labels": {
         "starred": false,
         "hidden": false,
         "trashed": false,
```

Comment: It works for the files. The Changes resource doesnt' have that option so I have to check each file after listing the changes. I want to optimize it on the Changes check. But I believe there's no way. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I'm not sure if you pasted this comment to the wrong answer, but it's incorrect v s. my answer. I've updated my answer to demonstrate the trashed label

Comment: And how can I use it to list the changes without the trashed files? I know i can filter the result, but what I want is it to be done on the Drive server side. I know I can do Files.list().setQ("trashed=false").execute() I'd like to know if there's a way to do the same thing on the Changes.list()